# What are the efficiency implications of using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

What is the difference between these 2 methods used to read characters from a file.

**FIRST**

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader( new File( "file.txt") );
int x = 0;
while( ( x = fr.read() ) != -1 ) {
    System.out.println( (char) x );
}
```

**SECOND**

```
BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( new File( "file.txt") ) );
int x = 0;
while( ( x = bfr.read() ) != -1 ) {
    System.out.println( (char) x );
}
```

Both the codes read the characters from the file and write it on the console.

**Which one of the method is more efficient and why ?** *Or it's the same thing ?*

Comment: Which was faster when you tried it? Why do you think it might be faster? What does the Javadoc for BufferedReader say?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thus spake the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html):

> In general, each read request made of a Reader causes a corresponding read request to be made of the underlying character or byte stream. It is therefore advisable to wrap a BufferedReader around any Reader whose read() operations may be costly, such as FileReaders and InputStreamReaders.

Comment: +1 usefulness; and I'd give an extra +1 for "thus spake" but unfortunately I can't :)

Comment: what is meant by `underlying character or byte stream`. what is it ?

Comment: @grassPro: for example, the filesystem.

Comment: I think the best way to describe streams is to think of them as data which flows from a source -- such as a hard drive or an internet connection.

Comment: +1 for the doc reference (why don't people read the doc before asking such questions?)

Comment: @cwallenpoole: Neither. I think Nietzsche personally.

Comment: Not completely following, unfortunately :P. "each read request made of a Reader causes a corresponding read request to be made of the underlying character or byte stream." How does the "corresponding read request" compromise efficiency and how does buffered reader resolve that shortcoming?

Answer (score 15):

Consider a water tank 5km away from you. For every bucket of water you had to travel 5km. For reducing your effort, you bring a small tank and fill it once for 3-4 days. Then full your buckets from the small water tank, inside your house.

In above example the water tank 5km away is a file on the hard disk, If you use a bare reader, it is like travelling 5km for every bucket of water. So you bring a small tank(BufferedReader).

Answer (score 0):

Just a little addition to @cwallenpoole's answer. There is also difference in the interface. For example, in BufferedReader there is a nice method readLine(), which I use heavily.